# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'onMemberDareLoaded(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple application, where there is a login page, on logging in a Dashboard (recycler view is there with card view along with onClick()).

**DashboardAdapter**

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String selected = mdList.getName();
                dashboardView.onMemberDataLoaded(selected);
                //GeneralUtils.showAlertDialog(activity, activity.getString(R.string.card_view) + " " + mdList.getName());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Dashboard Fragment**

```
public void onMemberDataLoaded(String memberList) {
  GeneralUtils.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), getActivity().getString(R.string.clicked_on) + " " + memberList);
    }
}
```

onMemberDataLoaded comes from a interface DashboardView which is implemented in Fragment

Comment: Hi Sobiya, Can you please show us how you are initializing dashboardView variable ?

Comment: DashboardView dashboardView;

Answer (score 0):

dashboardView is null! You can check again your XML, your findElementById, or BindView to define why it is null!